# How to make md-datepicker refresh on external model updates

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I have a md-datepicker control. I need to update the model value from outside, but when I do that the control will not reflect the change.
However, a second md-datepicker control with the same model will propagate the changes.

What am I missing?

```js
angular.module('DatePick', ['ngMaterial']);

angular.module('DatePick').controller('Pick', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.nextDay = function() {
    $scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() + 1);
  };
  $scope.prevDay = function() {
    $scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() - 1);
  };
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="DatePick">
  <div ng-controller="Pick">
    <md-datepicker ng-model="date"></md-datepicker>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="date"></md-datepicker>
    {{date}}
    <button ng-click="prevDay()">-</button>
    <button ng-click="nextDay()">+</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Example fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hd7fd325/6/).

Comment: Did my anwser help you?

Answer (score 1):

I got help from the Material devs. See ticket [7045](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7054).
In short, .setDate() does not change the object, so the day change will not be detected. Instead, a new object needs to be created. This below works.

```
$scope.nextDay = function() {
  $scope.date = new Date($scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() + 1));
};
$scope.prevDay = function() {
  $scope.date = new Date($scope.date.setDate($scope.date.getDate() - 1));
};
```